# stringr: U_REGEX_BAD_INTERVAL error

Tags: regex, r, stringr, grepl

I have a regular expression that is correctly parsed by `grepl` but generates an error when used as `pattern` of `str_extract_all`.

I'm using `stringr` v1.0.0, `R` v3.2.3 under OSX.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30061371/r-regex-engine-changed-in-3-2-0) question a regex passed to a `stringr` generates a similar error, yet the solution proposed doesn't apply in my case.

```
require(stringr)

string <- "Decreto Legislativo 6 marzo 1992, n. 248; G.U. n. 77 del 1° aprile 1992"

it_months <- c("gennaio","febbraio","marzo","aprile","maggio","giugno","luglio",
               "agosto","settembre","ottobre","novembre","dicembre")
grep_it_date <- paste0("\\d{1-2}(º?) (", paste(it_months, collapse="|") ,") \\d{4}$")

grepl(grep_it_date, string)
# [1] TRUE

dates_from_string <- str_extract_all(tolower(string), grep_it_date, simplify = TRUE)
# Error in stri_extract_all_regex(string, pattern, simplify = simplify,  : 
#                                   Error in {min,max} interval. (U_REGEX_BAD_INTERVAL)
```

Comment: The solution in that question applies perfectly to your case. Just use `{min, max}` or `{max}` or `{min,}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change `\\d{1-2}` to `\\d{1,2}` as told in the error, since the interval separator is `,` and not `-`

Comment: Why it's OK in `grepl`?

Comment: Also do not include spaces in the interval syntax. `\\d{1, 2}` is invalid, whereas `\\d{1,2}` is valid.

Answer (score 0):

If we need to extract `6 marzo 1992` and `1° aprile 1992` from the 'string'

```
 grep_it_date <- paste0("[0-9]{1,2}([^0-9 ]?)\\s+(", paste(it_months, collapse="|") ,")\\s+\\d{4}")
 str_extract_all(tolower(string), grep_it_date)[[1]]
 #[1] "6 marzo 1992"   "1° aprile 1992"
```